# Rails: Track Points On A Weekly Basis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, points

In my current application, I need the ability to track points on a weekly basis so that the point totals for the user reset back to zero each week.  I was planning on using the gem merit: https://github.com/tute/merit to track points.

In my users profile I have a field that is storing the points.  What I have been unable to locate is how I can have rails on an auto basis for all users clear this field.

I have come across some information [Rails reset single column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198538/rails-reset-single-column)  I think this may be the answer in terms of resetting it every Sunday at a set time -- but I am uncertain on this last part and in addition where the code would go (model or controller)

Also, would welcome any suggestions if their is a better method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be better making a `Point` model, which `belongs_to :user`

This will allow you to add any points you want, and can then query the table based on the `created_at` column to get a `.count` of the points for the timespan you want

I can give you more info if you think it appropriate

---

**Models**

One principle we live by is to extend our models as much as possible

You want each model to hold *only* its data, thus ensuring more efficient db calls. I'm not super experienced with databases, but it's my opinion that having a lot of smaller models is more efficient than one huge model

So in your question, you wanted to assign some `points` to a user. The "right" way to do this is to store all the points perpetually; which can only be done with its own model

---

**Points**

```
#app/models/point.rb
Class Point < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end

#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :points
end
```

Points table could look like this:

```
points
id | user_id | value | created_at | updated_at
```

---

**Saving**

To save the points, you will literally just have to add extra records to the `points` table. The simplest way to achieve this will be to `merge` the params, like this:

```
#app/controllers/points_controller.rb
class PointsController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @points = Point.new
    end

    def create
        @points = Point.new(points_params)
        @points.save
    end

    private
    def points_params
        params.require(:points).permit(:value).merge(:user_id => current_user.id)
    end
end
```

You can define the "number" of points by setting in the `value` column (which I'd set as `default 1`). This will be how StackOverflow gives different numbers of points; by setting the `value` column differently ;)

---

**Counting**

To get weekly countings, you'll have to create some sort of function which will allow you to split the points by week. Like this:

```
#app/models/point.rb -> THIS NEEDS MORE WORK
def self.weekly
    where(:created_at => Time.now.next_week..Time.now.next_week.end_of_week)
end
```

That function won't work as it is
I'll sort out the function properly for you if you let me know a little more about how you'd like to record / display the weekly stats. Is it going to be operated via a cron job or something?

Comment: Rich -- Thanks for your suggestion -- I am very interested in this approach -- I am using belongs_to :user for other items and I like the idea of a "cleaner" user model (not having a field in the user model) -- I am still a little fuzzy on how the points model would be set up so I anxiously look forward to your additional info ---

Comment: THANK YOU.  The point model I completely understand.  RE: saving points -- If I want the points to be earned when the user accomplishes tasks which are stored in two separate models --- can I have it so as a task is completed and registered in DB -- it would add a  point to the point table -- regarding weekly counts at the end of the week points are tallied and the user gets something if they earn enough points -- I want the points to reset to 0 at the start of each week -- I believe I can use the Merit gem to accomplish some of the above but would welcome any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you might want to simply track the users points and the time that they got them. Then you can query for any 1 week period (or different periods if you decide you want all-time, annual, etc) and you won't lose historical data.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion -- similar to Rich's below -- so please take a look at my response below ---